# Assignment between custom slice type and the underlying type

Tags: go, types

Go assignment shows error for `int` but not for `[]int` slice.

working code [here](https://play.golang.org/p/G5dsbfp1wDS)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type testType []int

func main() {
    var i testType
    var t []int
    t = i

    fmt.Println("Hello, playground", t, i)
}
```

However, if it is `int` type the compiler will surely show errors [here](https://play.golang.org/p/QzH6mzuPggU):

```
cannot use i (type testType) as type int in assignment
```

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type testType int

func main() {
    var i testType
    var t int
    t = i

    fmt.Println("Hello, playground", t, i)
}
```

Why does it error out for the custom `int` type and not the custom `[]int` type?

Comment: So you _want_ it to complain? Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is defined in [Go language specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability) for assignment types:

> A value x is assignable to a variable of type T ("x is assignable to
>   T") if one of the following conditions applies:
>
> - x's type is identical to T.
> - x's type V and T have identical underlying types and at least one of V or T is not a defined type.
> - T is an interface type and x implements T.
> - x is a bidirectional channel value, T is a channel type, x's type V and T have identical element types, and at least one of V or T is
>     not a defined type.
> - x is the predeclared identifier nil and T is a pointer, function, slice, map, channel, or interface type.
> - x is an untyped constant representable by a value of type T.

In your case `[]int` is a slice and not named type. That's why the compiler did not complain. For more information on named types go through [Go specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types) for types:

> A type determines the set of values and operations specific to values
>   of that type. Types may be named or unnamed. Named types are specified
>   by a (possibly qualified) type name; unnamed types are specified using
>   a type literal, which composes a new type from existing types.

Comment: Is there a way of casting []int to testType and reverse? Just qurious